# JavaScript function that Randomly replaces x percent of Letters

Tags: javascript

I need a JavaScript function that goes through all of the elements of a page that belong to a specific class and replace at random 'X' percent of the characters. The idea is to obscure the message by varying degree.  The more obscure the message, the more challenging it is to decipher.

I just started by attempting a single element with getElementById, but got stuck there already with the line *s[i]='_';* . In addition to this problem of replacing a specific character, I actually need to perform the function on every paragraph that belongs to the member of a specific class... not just one single id element.

Edit: There is a problem with my approach: special characters like &amp; . However, this is a minor issue for my use, and I can accept that to get started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function obscure(percent){
            var s = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML;
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){
                 //return a random integer between 0 and 100
                 var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(percent+1)));
                     if(rand < percent){
                         s[i]='_';
                     }
            }
            document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = s;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="obscure(50)">obscure</a>
    <p id="change">
        To be, or not to be: that is the question:
        Whether 'tis nobler ...
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function obscure(percent){
   var s = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML;
   for(var i=0; i < s.length; i++){
     if(Math.floor(Math.random()*100) < percent){
        s = s.substr(0,i-1) + '_' + s.substr(i+1);
     }
   }
   document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = s;
}
```

Your string assignment wasn't working (you can't change individual characters in a js string since behind the scenes they're immutable), and your conditional wasn't accurate either (you want to create a random number from 1 - 100 so you times the random part by 100).

As for traversing all elements of a certain class, I recommend you use a js library for that. I'm a jQuery guy, but there are lots out there!

Comment: Thanks!  Regarding JQuerry, it is moving up on my list of things I need to learn.

Comment: @xavier, that is very much the topic of another discussion.

Comment: You can do the same thing without breaking it.

Comment: @Xavierm Do you have a link about that?

Comment: I just spent 10 minutes writing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850316/javascript-function-that-randomly-replaces-x-percent-of-letters/5859495#5859495

Answer (score 1):

A code that doesn't break DOM-2 & + events:

```
function obscure( element, percent ) {
    if ( percent > 100 ) {
        throw new Error( "percent can't be over 100!" );
    }
    // Prepare
    var _ = "_",
    alreadyChanged = [ ],
    character,
    i,
    j,
    innerText = "",
    innerTextLength,
    getTextNodes = function ( textNodes, textNodesLength, parentNode ) {
        var index,
        length,
        node,
        nodes = parentNode.childNodes,
        nodeValue,
        tagName,
        i = nodes.length;
        while ( i-- ) {
            node = nodes[ i ];
            if ( node.nodeType === 1 ) { // Element
                tagName = node.tagName;
                if ( tagName !== "SCRIPT" && tagName !== "NOSCRIPT" ) {
                    getTextNodes( textNodes, textNodesLength, node );
                }
            } else if ( node.nodeType === 3 ) { // Text
                nodeValue = node.nodeValue;
                if ( nodeValue.search( /\S/ ) !== -1 ) {
                    textNodes.push( node );
                    textNodesLength.push( nodeValue.length );
                    innerText += nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    max,
    random = function ( max ) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random( ) * ( max + 1 ) );
    },
    textNodes = [ ],
    textNodesLength = [ ];

    // Get all textNodes
    getTextNodes( textNodes, textNodesLength, element );
    innerTextLength = innerText.length;

    // Get rid all all characters that are already the one we might change to
    j = 0;
    while ( ( i = innerText.indexOf( _, i + 1 ) ) !== -1 ) {
        alreadyChanged[ i ] = true;
        ++j;
    }

    // Change the content
    i = Math.round( ( percent / 100 ) * innerTextLength );
    if ( i + j > innerTextLength ) {
        i = innerTextLength - j;
    }
    max = innerTextLength - 1;
    while ( i-- ) {
        do {
            j = random( max );
        } while ( alreadyChanged[ j ] );
        alreadyChanged[ j ] = true;
        innerText = innerText.substring( 0, j - 1 ) + _ + innerText.substring( j );
    }

    // Replace textNodes' content
    i = textNodes.length;
    index = innerText.length;
    while( i-- ) {
        length = textNodesLength[ i ];
        index -= length;
        textNodes[ i ].nodeValue = innerText.substr( index, length );
    }

}
// Example
obscure( document.body, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're multiplying **Math.random()** by **percent + 1**, you're guaranteed to have **rand** be less than **percent**.  Therefore, your entire string will be underscores.

Instead, set rand like so:

```
var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
```

As for selecting elements by class, I'd recommend using jQuery.  It has a nice syntax to grab elements using CSS.  For example, you could get all the paragraphs with a specific class in jQuery like so:

```
for ( var paragraphToObscure in $( "p.someClass" )) {
    // Do your obscuring code in here on paragraphToObscure...
}
```

Where **someClass** is the CSS class you're looking for on each **<p>** element.

You can download the jQuery JavaScript files from here: [jQuery JavaScript files](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can easily identify all of the elements with the class:

```
$("#obscure50").click( function () {
    var percent = 50;
    $(".classToObscure").each( function () {
                var s = $(this).html();
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<s.length;i++){
                 //return a random integer between 0 and 100
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(percent+1)));
                    if(rand < percent){
                        s[i]='_';
                    }
                }
                $(this).html(s);
    });
});
....

<a href="#" id="obscure50">obscure</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have an extra closing parenthases on your `Math.floor()` line. JavaScript error console is your friend.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at it that should hopefully work on all elements of a class.  I don't know how much support getElementByClassNames has so I'd also recommend looking at jQuery or another library.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/Taf4n/

I've put together another demo that shows you some performance metrics using http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/

Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/Taf4n/5/

```
var percent = 50;
var obscure = document.getElementsByClassName('obscure');
for (i = 0; i < obscure.length; i++) {
    var element = obscure[i];
    var text = element.innerHTML;
    var str = "";
    for (j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
        //return a random integer between 0 and 100
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100));
        if (rand < percent) {
            //Can't Change a String element directly               
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String
            str = str + '_';
        } else {
            str = str + text[j];
        }
    }
    var x = str;
}
```